# C# Visual Studio Create Setup file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a small program that I made in c# using VS 2012.
I want to make a setup.exe file, so I did `BUILD -> Publish "Project Name"` but it created four files:

1. setup.exe
2. autorun.inf
3. *.application file
4. "Application Files" folder

all those files are in a folder named "publish".

When I press the setup.exe file, it does installs my program, though it doesn't give me an option to choose where I want to save my program, and I can't figure out where it installs it automatclly.

thank you for your help.

Comment: I usually use the option to publish to CD.  The CD option will create the setup folder on any disk system (not just CD).  Then when you run setup.exe is gives all the options.  You can copy the publish folder(s) to another PC just like commercial software,

Comment: Now When I publish the defualt option is CD, and it is the same...

Comment: Normally setup.exe will install in the Program File folder and give option which folder to install.  The program should have a shortcut in the Start Button (All Programs) depending on version of windows.  The setup also creates a shortcut on the desktop.  And finally it should be on control panel installed programs.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [wixtool](http://wixtoolset.org/) instead of vs installer. The tool gives you more options and customization feature.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using [Windows Installer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer):

- Go to *extensions* and add it by searching it in the *Search* box.
- Add a new project into the same solution, and choose a new *Installer* project. Select *Setup Wizard*.
- Follow the steps.